# Why A non-parameterless constructor is still ok?

Tags: c#, class, generics, inheritance

Here is the interface definition specifies it must use a parameterless constructor to instantiate a new class of T, fine.

```
public interface IDatabase<T> where T : class, new()
{...}
```

But the concrete class:

```
public class MyDatabase<T> : IDatabase<T> where T : class, new()
{
  public MyDatabase(string conString)
  {...}
}
```

Questions

1 - if the first colon means MyDatabase is to implement the IDatabase interface, why still needs the second colon to specify the interface's constraints again?

2 - is the inside constructor `public MyDatabase(string conString)` an override to the interface, if so then the second colon is not necessary, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1 - if the first colon means MyDatabase is to implement the IDatabase interface, why still needs the second colon to specify the interface's constraints again?

Those two type parameter declarations for T are two completely different things both named T. The first T has a requirement placed upon it: any type provided as the type argument to the interface must meet these conditions.  You've then used a different thing also named T that is supposed to meet those conditions.  If you don't have the where clause then we have no guarantee that the T in the class will actually meet the conditions required by the interface!

> is the inside constructor public MyDatabase(string conString) an override to the interface, if so then the second colon is not necessary, right?

I don't understand the question. I don't know what "an override to the interface" means.

From the comments to another answer:

> If the interface already specifies the constraints, why does an implementing class of this interface should repeat those constraints again? Of course there cannot be a right answer to this question here. This should be addressed to the people at Microsoft that decided to implement it that way, everything else is just speculation.

Well I am that person and I wrote an article about precisely that:

https://ericlippert.com/2013/07/15/why-are-generic-constraints-not-inherited/

Comment: Ahh, the same T could be a totally two diff things!! From a day-to-day programmer's point of view, they are usually the same. However, it's totally possible they are not. But if the second colon is taken off, can we say the concrete implementation's T is actually the same as the interface's?

Comment: **"an override to the interface"** meant overriding of OO programming. But now I think it's more an overloading.

Comment: Actually Eric's already answered above, taking out 2nd colon would not guarantee the concrete T is the same as interface's T. Even though it is for many programmers, but it's perfect to specify again to enforce it.

Answer (score 7):

The additional constraints are required because you haven't provided any type information about `T` in your concrete class implementation that matches the interface.

The compiler simply does not determine that `T` in your concrete class will match the generic constraint requirements of the interface. As a result, the compiler insists that you use "redundant" type constraints to enforce that they are compatible types.

Comment: Why do you think that the compiler can't determine that the `T` used in the concrete class isn't the same as the `T` from the interface? Since `MyDatabase<T>` implements `IDatabase<T>`, it is quite obvious that the `T` on the implementing class is the same `T` from the interface which already provided the generic constraints.

Comment: I'm not talking about ***consuming*** the concrete class, I'm talking about specifically about ***implementing*** the generic constraint requirements of the interface ***on*** the generic class.  Obviously when creating an instance of the class the compiler can infer the type.  If I didn't make that clear in my answer, I'd appreciate feedback on clarifying the language :)

Comment: Same thought/question, T is a placeholder. So it's up to the consumption when it's being used, for example, `MyDatabase<questions> mdb = new MyDatabase(); `

Comment: I think it's more about the design of the .NET generics question. If the interface already specifies the constraints, why does an implementing class of this interface should *repeat* those constraints again? Of course there cannot be a right answer to this question here. This should be addressed to the people at Microsoft that decided to implement it that way, everything else is just speculation.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I think I see your point and I've subtly changed the wording in my answer.  It isn't so much that the compiler doesn't have the ability if so implemented, but rather that the design never provided a way for it to do so.  As a result, the compiler requires the implementing class to repeat the constraints.  I assume that they decided that the benefit outweighed the cost of implementation.

Comment: No, it's not the compiler that requires the implementing class to repeat the constraints. It's the people that wrote the .NET generics implementation that decided it to be that way. Why they did so is not something that we should be speculating about on here. That's a completely subjective story and it is the reason why such kind of questions are quite off-topic on StackOverflow. They simply cannot lead to a *right* answer.

Comment: Well now we're just straying into the semantics.  The compiler merely enforces the .NET generics spec which ultimately was determined far outside the scope of this answer/discussion and I'm in full agreement with you that additional speculation isn't useful.

Comment: I invite all of you to consider the problem more deeply than you have thus far. Considering "easy" cases is not interesting; the language needs a clear unambiguous rule for *all* cases.  For example: `class G<T, U> where T : X where U : Y {}
class H<V> : G<V, V> {}`  What constraints should be deduced for V?

Comment: @EricLippert thanks as always for your brilliant examples and insight :).  Based on your example, is it fair to state that there wasn't an unambiguous rule that could encompass all cases and as such the compiler does not infer generic constraints and rather requires them to be re-implemented by the concrete type?

Comment: @EricLippert: in the case of `class H<V> : G<V, V> {}` couldn't the compiler could use the *intersection* of the 2 constraints from the interface definition about `V`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Sure; I invite you to devise an algorithm that takes *any two .NET types* and produces a third type which is their intersection. This is a feature hitherto not found in .NET. Remember to take generic covariance and contravariance into account in your algorithm.

Comment: @EricLippert, that's a very good point. I am completely unable to devise such algorithm. But couldn't the compiler in those ambiguous cases just throw an error? And in all other 90% of the cases just spare us the code repetition? I guess it's the eternal question: convention over configuration :-)

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Let's suppose you could. Let's just make up some random types: `class Banana<T> where T : Coffee<T> {}
class Coffee<U> : Banana<Giraffe<U>> where U : INewspaper<Coffee<U>> {}
class Giraffe<V> : Coffee<Banana<V>> where V : IVehicle<V> {}` Do you wish additional constraints to be inherited in each of these types?  Can we guarantee that the algorithm which determines those constraints terminates? If it is unable to find a consistent set of constraints, what error message should be produced?

Comment: And most important: what feature of C# would you like to see cut in order to make room in the budget for this one?

Comment: I absolutely agree with you on this one. In order to ship a feature, this feature needs to be designed, implemented, tested and documented. The effort might not be worth in this case. Personally I am fine with the current implementation :-D